# express authentication cookie fields are undefined in getauth method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, express

I have react client working on 3000 and express on 5000 when logging in, cookie fields are set with no problem but when trying to get isauth it shows as undefined.

//login log message of cookie

login successful
session isAuth set to true
Session {
cookie: {
path: '/',
_expires: 2024-01-21T04:01:13.874Z,
originalMaxAge: 7200000,
httpOnly: true,
secure: false
},
isAuth: true,
username: {
_id: new ObjectId('65ac7ae2bfdff2c762de42b8'),
username: 'asd',
password: '$2a$12$1SJgC2sxqQosb.bI5PH4QO7Jrv9uFKulhGeAON89rjt08tqbxyjG.',
__v: 0
}
}

// isauth request

checking if user is authenticated
Session {
cookie: {
path: '/',
_expires: 2024-01-21T04:01:17.393Z,
originalMaxAge: 7200000,
httpOnly: true,
secure: false
}
}

source code:

//app.js

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Login from './pages/Login';
import Home from './pages/Home';
import Register from './pages/Register';
import Dashboard from './pages/Dashboard';
import { useState,useEffect } from "react";
import { Navigate } from "react-router";
function App() {

  const [isauth, setIsauth] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
      
    const getAuth = async () => {
      try {
          const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/isauth', {
              method: 'GET',
              withCredentials: true,
              credentials: 'include',
          });
  
          console.log(response);  
        
          const parseRes = await response.json();
          console.log(parseRes);
          parseRes === true ? setIsauth(true) : setIsauth(false);
      } catch (err) {
          console.error(err.message);
      }
  };
      getAuth();
  }, []);


  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/Login' element={<Login />} />
        <Route path='/Home' element={<Home />} />
        <Route path='/Register' element={<Register />} />
        <Route
            path="/Dashboard"
            element={isauth ? <Dashboard isauth={isauth} /> : <Navigate to="/Login" />}
          />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

//server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 5000;
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cors = require('cors');
const session = require('express-session');
const passport = require('passport');
const MongoDBStore = require('connect-mongodb-session')(session);
const MongoDBSession = require('connect-mongodb-session')(session);
const UserModel = require('./models/User');
const mongoURI = "mongodb+srv://@cluster0.ql90ztk.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

mongoose.connect(mongoURI, {

  })
    .then(() => console.log("Connected to db"))
    .catch((err) => console.error("Error connecting to database:", err));
  
const store = new MongoDBSession({
    uri: mongoURI,
    collection: 'mySessions',
    });

app.use(
    session({
        secret: 'secret',
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false,
        store: store,
        cookie: {
            maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 2,
            secure: false,
            httpOnly: true,
        },
    })
);
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors({
  origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
  credentials: true,
  methods: 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE' ,
  allowedHeaders: 'Content-Type, Authorization',
}));

app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
    console.log("attempting to login");
    const { username, password } = req.body;

    const user = await UserModel.findOne({ username });
    console.log(user);
    if (!user) {
        console.log("user not found");
        return res.status(401).json({ message: "User not found" });
    }

    const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
    if (!isMatch) {
        console.log("incorrect password");
        return res.status(401).json({ message: "Incorrect password" });
    }

    req.session.isAuth = true;
    req.session.username = user;
    console.log("login successful");
    console.log("session isAuth set to true");
    console.log(req.session);

    res.json({ message: "Login successful" });
});

app.get("/isauth", (req, res) => {
    console.log("Request Headers:", req.headers);
    console.log("checking if user is authenticated");
    console.log(req.session);
    console.log(req.session.isAuth);
    if (req.session.isAuth) {
        res.send(true);
    } else {
        res.send(false);
    }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`);
});
```

I have been stuck here for some time now, what am I missing?

I have react client working on 3000 and express on 5000 when logging in, cookie fields are set with no problem but when trying to get isauth it shows as undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after experimenting with it for a while I realized that I have not enabled third-party cookies from the browser. After enabling that it started working.

Checklist to those who are having similar problems (with 2 ports running):

1)Allow third-party cookies from the browser
2)Check cors configuration from express. Include another origin ex:  `origin: 'http://localhost:3000'`  and allow `credentials: true`
3) check `cookie.secure: false` for HTTP